# How to make a 3-Color Noise texture in Substance Designer?

Tags: textures

I am trying to make a seamless leafy texture in Substance Designer procedurally.

Basically I want 3 colored noise from scratch. Even two color would be ok but not just black and white.

In the following image I have the effect I want, (I do note its not JUST black n white, it is greyscale). I want greens and yellows in there and NO black or white at all in there. Essentially I just want to change the black value to be green, and white to be yellowish brown. Then it would be the exact effect I need for the texture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change greyscale to colors simple use Gradient Map node and specify colors you want there (i.e. green and yellow). You can add any other colors in between too.

[image]